# CSS 3 out of 4 custom fonts don't load

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts

I can't seem to make custom fonts load in Firefox 54.0 and Chromium  59.0.3071.86. Looking at the Network tab in Firefox's element inspection tool, I see no font being loaded/downloaded, same with Chromium.

Here's the relevant CSS: https://hastebin.com/raw/quyivirosa
And here's the HTML: https://hastebin.com/iciwavoyus.xml

I've checked, and the URLs to the fonts are all correct, so I have no idea why it refuses to work. What does work is the font in the navbar, but I'm guessing that one is being loaded locally, since it's installed on my system.

Is there something I've done wrong...? I've searched around, and could not find any solutions to my problem.

Comment: check your server for 404 errors. Make sure that the web server is not refusing the woff, woff2 and eot files.   I found my server (IIS) was until I changed the web config file.

Comment: You are required to post the relevant markup here that shows the problem. Not your site which will change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Bindrid: Good one. Looked at the logs, and there were no entries for any errors related to the font files, nor there were any entries for today. Also, I tried downloading the files manually, and it worked as well.

Comment: and you have a folder called fonts with the font files in them?

Comment: @Bindrid: yes, I do: https://jpopfantasia.cf/fonts/

Answer (score 0):

I found two errors in your css that, as soon as I fixed them, the fonts started working.

I changed

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'DejaVu Condensed'; !important
        src: url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed.eot');
        src: url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-  opentype'),
            url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed.woff') format('woff'),;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

to

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'DejaVu Condensed' !important; 
        src: url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.eot');
        src: url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('/fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

On line two, !important should be inside the semicolon.
On line six, I removed the coma that is right before the semicolon. 
Once fixed, the font face kicked in

Comment: Thanks! I should've looked more closely at syntax. I also made the corrections, and unfortunately the fonts still don't load...  I've also tried to remove the !important rule, and that seems to have changed the font a bit, but still doesn't look right, nor does the browser load the fonts...

Comment: I see a duplicate name. 'UnDinaru' is being used for both 'UnDinaru' and 'UnDinaruBold'

Comment: this fonts out in the public so I can see what they are suppose to look like?

Comment: Yes, that's because the bold and normal weight of the font is split into two files. And sure, the fonts are open source, so you can get them here: https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/dejavu-sans    https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/gidole-regular    https://kldp.net/unfonts/release/2607-un-fonts-core-1.0.2-080608.tar.gz

Comment: now I am more confused, those are ttf files not woff or woff2

Comment: Yes, I took those and converted them using this: https://onlinefontconverter.com/.  I assumed since you wanted to take a look at them, you would need the original files. I'll remove the index.html for you to be able to get the woff* files.